# Text doen't appear after speech in adroid studio

Tags: java, android

Today i am posting my first question here in stackoverflow.
My app's subject is speech to text application all the app is working but the text doen't appear in its zone after saying the speech. So i am here asking you all for help.
Belong my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:hint="Tap Mic to Speak"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_mic_24" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And my main code:

```
   package com.example.translationapp;


   


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkPermission();

    final EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);


    final Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());


    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            //getting all the matches
            ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                    .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            //displaying the first match
            if (matches != null) {
                edittext.setText(matches.get(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
                    edittext.setHint("You will see input here");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                    edittext.setText("");
                    edittext.setHint("Listening...");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}


private void checkPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
}
```

So please again and thank you all for your time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I would start by adding some debug logging in your RecogitionListener#onError and RecognitionListener#onResults methods to see what's getting called.  Alternatively, you can run the debugger and put breakpoints on these methods and see what's going on that way.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't get you told me can you explain more

Comment: You should add logging to your code to help you debug it.  Please read about how to [write and view logs with logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) and the [logcat command tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) for more information.